# react-native-router-flux: Navbar buttons need to access scene component methods

Tags: react-native

I am inserting a rightButton into react-native-router-flux using the `renderRightButton` api.  The problem I ran into is that the rightButton needs to access a method within the component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
          <Scene
              key="firstScene"
              component={FirstScene}
              title="First scene"
              rightTitle="Apply"
              renderRightButton={this.getRightButton}
          />
      </Router>
    )
  }

  getRightButton() {
    return(

      // someMethodOnFirstSceneComponent lives on the FirstScene component

      <View onPress{this.someMethodOnFirstSceneComponent}>
        <Text>
          Invoke Function from Scene Component
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
};
```

One option would be to put all of the data currently in the state of `FirstScene` into a redux reducer and then put the `someMethodOnFirstSceneComponent` on the `FirstScene` component.  However, I am trying to keep state within components and not rely on reducers because from my experience, it keeps things easier to reason about.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to do that. Not a very nice solution, but it works. I'm setting onRight method in the component constructor

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.component.onRight = () => {
      console.warn("call from my onRight function")}
    }
  }
```